# lxml --pretty_print-- write file problem

Tags: python, lxml

I am write a raw data to xml file python program, in my design,we get the raw data line by line,
then write it into xml file like:

```
`<root>\n
  <a> value </a>\n
  <b> value </b>\n
</root>
```

The first time i write into xml file with pretty_print=True, i got what i want, but when the second
time i read the file, get the element root, --add-- new elemnts then save it back with pretty_print=True, but i can not get what i want,it just like:

```
...\n
<c> value </c></root>
```

`
what's wrong with lxml? Or my fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the answer in the lxml faq: [Why doesn't the pretty_print option reformat my XML output?](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output)