# ElementTree.write doesn't pretty_print on second pass

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I'm having an issue with formatting xml when writing to an xml file.  The issue is, the first time I write to the xml file, the xml is formatted properly using pretty_print=True.  Any subsequent attempts to append to the xml file are not formatted properly.  The xml is written, but not formatted.  My code looks like:

```
#does the library.xml file exist?
if os.path.isfile(libraryFile):
    library = ET.ElementTree()
    library.parse(libraryFile)
else:
    #the library.xml does not exist at the given path
    library = ET.ElementTree(project.getBoilerplateLibrary(path)) 

root = library.getroot()

root.append(xml) #xml is a lxml Element object

f = open(libraryFile, 'w')
library.write(f, pretty_print=True)
f.close()
```

The first time we write to the file I get something like:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </element>
</root>
```

Any subsequent attempts to append to this file end up looking like:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </element><element><bleep>bloop</bleep></element></root>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ covers this answer: [Why doesn't the pretty print options reformat my XML output](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output)

This question has also been asked before on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as [lxml pretty print write file problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407108/lxml-pretty-print-write-file-problem).

It is unfortunately a side effect of using XML where whitespace (unfortunately) definitely matters.

Comment: Thanks X-Istence!  I guess I didn't know what to search for.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Configuring the parser to user remove_blank_text did the trick for me.